# On a Geometric Proof (Ahlfors) that the Cross ratio is real if and only if four points lie on a circle or straight line

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, cross-ratio

> The cross-ratio $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ is real if and only if the four points lie on a circle or on a straight line.

I know this question has been asked numerous times on MSE, but I have a specific question with respect to how Ahlfors proves this on page 79 of his book.  He says,

"This is evident by elementary geometry, for we obtain $$\text{arg}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=\text{arg}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}-\text{arg}\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_4}$$ and if the points lie on a circle this difference of angles is either $0$ or $\pm\pi$"

Could someone elaborate a bit on this for me?  I see that he's splitting up the cross-ratio using arguments, and I know that straight lines and circles are the same in $\mathbb{R}\cup\infty$, but I am not seeing how the geometry proves both directions of the statement.  I would appreciate it very much!  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]In the diagram above, by the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem), the angles at $z_1,z_2$ are equal because they subtend the same chord $z_3z_4$.  If $z_1,z_2$ are on opposite sides of the chord the sum of the subtended angles is $\pi$.

Recalling that $\text{arg}\frac{w}{z}$ is the angle between $w$ and $z$,
in the first case (angles equal),
$$\text{arg}\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}=\alpha=\text{arg}\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_4}.$$
and from there we see that $\text{arg}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=0 \implies (z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)\in\mathbb{R}$.

The argument is similar if $z_1,z_2$ are on opposite sides of the chord.

To go in the other direction we observe that
$(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)\in\mathbb{R}\implies \text{arg}(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=0 \text{ or }\pi,$ and therefore the angles at $z_1,z_2$ subtended by the segment $z_3z_4$ are either equal or supplementary.  In either case we can conclude that the points are either collinear or concyclic.

**Bonus mnemonic.** The cross ratio formula can be difficult to remember, whether it is for the complex plane, or for collinear points in projective geometry. This geometric interpretation gives a good mnemonic.  In the diagram there are two paths to get from $z_3$ to $z_4$ via the other points: $z_3\to z_1\to z_4$, and $z_3\to z_2\to z_4$.  For each path take the ratios of the path segments, and then the ratio of these ratios:
$$ \frac{z_3\to z_1}{z_1\to z_4}:\frac{z_3\to z_2}{z_2\to z_4}$$

Rewriting $w\to z$ as $w-z$ we get (*)
$$ \frac{z_3-z_1}{z_1-z_4}:\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_2-z_4},$$

which is equivalent to Ahlfors' definition

$$ \frac{z_1-z_3}{z_1-z_4}:\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_4}.$$

(*) Technically, instead of $w-z$ we should have rewritten $w\to z$ in 'vector' style as $z-w$ but $z-w=-(w-z)$ and all the minus signs cancel.  This way we get a cross ratio formula that's easy to 'read' as two paths from $z_3$ to $z_4$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I will award the bounty as soon as it lets me.  Right now, it says I have 17 more hours until it can be awarded.  Thank you!

Comment: @User7238 You're welcome!  I've added a 'bonus mnemonic' section, which is something I came up with when I was first learning cross ratios and trying to figure out the geometry behind them.